# CentOS 7 kickstart arguments

Tags: centos7, kickstart

How to pass arguments to a kickstart installation procedure on CentOS 7?

I need to install multiple servers that have similar configuration except some differences that I would like to pass to kickstart before installation.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a syslinux simple boot menu,

https://www.syslinux.org/doc/menu.txt

Based on the menu selection invoke kernel with different parameters, eg.

```
label foo 
kernel vmlinuz
append initrd=initrd.img inst.ks=hd:LABEL=DATA:/path machinetype=foo

label bar 
kernel vmlinuz
append initrd=initrd.img inst.ks=hd:LABEL=DATA:/path machinetype=bar
```

This kernel param thus passed can be parsed in your kickstart file,

```
%post
machinetype=$(grep -o machinetype=[a-zA-Z]* /proc/cmdline| cut -d '=' -f 2)

# $machinetype now contains the input passed during boot.
```